# A few images of a PHP app hosted on Heroku are not getting loaded

Tags: php, git, heroku

I am using Github as SCM & have enable auto-deploy on Heroku. I am trying Heroku for a simple HTML, CSS, JS app & Used PHP for deployment. All my images are available in Git, relative path given for images is also correct. Still some of the images are not reflecting on page & giving 404 whereas most of them do appear. What can be it's reason?

Here's code snippet

```css
.bgimg1 {
            background-image: url('images/Top_Image.jpg');
        }
```

```html
<body class="background">
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div class=" bgimg1">My top content </div>

<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="img" height="50%" width="100%">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="img" height="50%" width="100%">
                </div> 
            </div>
</body>
```

and here is project structure.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you reference the correct images, watch out for lower/upper case:
You are referencing `*.jpg` (lower case) in your html when the filenames really are `.JPG` (upper case).

Corrected code:

```
.bgimg1 {
  background-image: url('images/Top_Image.JPG');
}

<body class="background">
  <div class="loader"></div>
  <div class=" bgimg1">My top content </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="images/1.JPG" alt="img" height="50%" width="100%">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="img" height="50%" width="100%">
    </div> 
  </div>
</body>
```